# Im getting an error in my react and rest api app where one of my variables is coming back undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, undefined, react-fullstack

thank you for your time if youre reading this, im making a full stack app with react and rest api and im encountering an error as such:

```
TypeError: errors is undefined
    submit UserSignUp.js:53
    promise callback*UserSignUp/this.submit UserSignUp.js:51
    React 17
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:653
    React 24
    js index.js:8
    Webpack 7
```

the part where this error is throwing is right here:

```
context.userController.createUser(user)
    .then( errors => {
      if (errors.length) {
        this.setState( {errors});
      } else {
        context.actions.signIn(emailAddress,password)
        .then( () => {this.props.history.push('/authenticated')}  );
      }
      })
    .catch( err => { // handle rejected promises
      console.log(err);
      this.props.history.push('/error'); // push to history stack
    })
  }
}
```

heres my createUser function code:

```
async createUser(user){
    const response = await this.call_api('/users', 'POST', user);
    if (response.status === 201) {
      return [];
    }
    else if (response.status === 400) {
      return response.json().then(data => {
        return data.errors;
      });
    }
    else {
      throw new Error();
    }
  }
  }
```

heres the code handiling post / users

```
router.post('/users', asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = req.body;

    if(user.password)
    {
        user.password = bcryptjs.hashSync(user.password);
    };

    try
    {
        await User.create(user);
        res.status(201).location('/').end();
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.name === 'SequelizeValidationError' || error.name === 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError')
     {
            const errorMsg = [];

            error.errors.map((err) => errorMsg.push(err.message));
            res.status(400).json({ error: errorMsg });
        } else
        {
            next(error);
        };
    };
}));
```

Im really not sure whats going on with my errors variable here so if anyone could help me that would be great heres my github link:
https://github.com/zakMossy/react-and-rest-api-project-10

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code where the error is thrown?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan I think this is what you meant

Comment: Thanks. Can you also add the `createUser` function code?

Comment: yes @ArunKumarMohan i put everything there for ya

Comment: I was referring to the `createUser` function defined in `UserController.js`.  And can you share the API code handling requests to `POST /users` @zakmosbacher?

Comment: oops sorry about that @ArunKumarMohan

Comment: No worries! @zakmosbacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `createUser` function code returns `data.errors` if the response status is not 201. But your API sends the errors in the `error` key. Update the key to `errors` in your API route handler and you should be good to go.

```js
 res.status(400).json({ errors: errorMsg });
```